# Python equality operator not working with discord.py IDs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I set up a very simple command for a Discord bot. This is supposed to, in response to the `!positions` command, check the author and channel, and if the author is me, and the channel is my DM channel with the bot, do something (like send a reply message).

The ID of my account is `285538805728149504`. When the command `!positions` is run, it outputs this:

```
Author ID 285538805728149504
DM channel 814250853669666887
Current channel 814250853669666887
```

You can see that the author ID it prints out is *exactly* the same as the hardcoded user ID I'm comparing it to. You can also see that the two channel IDs compared are *exactly* the same.

However, it doesn't get past any of the `if` statements.

Here's the code:

```
@commands.command()
async def positions(self, ctx):

    positions_file = Path("positions.json")
    positions = json.loads(positions_file.read_text())

    message_author = ctx.message.author.id

    print("id " + str(message_author))
    print("dm channel " + str(ctx.message.author.dm_channel.id))
    print("Current channel " + str(ctx.message.channel.id))

    my_id = "285538805728149504"
    if message_author == my_id:
        print("Author ID is my ID")
        if ctx.message.author.dm_channel.id == ctx.message.channel.id:
            print("Channel ID is my DM channel")
            await ctx.message.author.dm_channel.send("reply")
```

Why can't I successfully compare these numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're comparing a `str` object and an `int` object in this line:

```py
if message_author == my_id:
```

Note that an `id` by default is an integer (documentation on that [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20author#discord.User.id)).

Either change your `my_id` to be an integer, or use `str(message_author)` in the previously mentioned line!

Comment: You're right, looks like the problem was related to the types! I removed the quotation marks to make it an integer, but it still didn't work until I forced both the hard-coded ID and the variable ID to be `int`s using the built-in `int()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Change `is` to `==` and try it.
Also try putting the `ctx.message.author.id` into a var

Comment: Oh no, I'm sorry, I was actually testing to see if `is` would work better than `==`, and I forgot to switch it back before asking this question. I still have the same problem when I use `==`. I tried storing the IDs in a variable (question has been updated with my current code), but that doesn't help, either.